# Serve static assets with an efficient cache policy with html4

Tags: php, html, cache-control, pagespeed-insights

I am doing audits for my website in order to improve the performance and I am getting the following advise:

## "Serve static assets with an efficient cache policy - A long cache lifetime can speed up repeat visits to your page."

I found that I have to add the following code in my header:

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="public">
```

but the advise is still here when I am doing google speed insight.

So I tried another code I found, I added it in my .htaccess:

```
# 1 Month for most static assets
<filesMatch ".(css|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|ico)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
</filesMatch>
```

But it is not working either...

I don't know how to do it and I can't find a good solution on internet.

Comment: Can you share some URLs that insights say should have an efficient cache policy? You can see that under 'Serve static assets with an efficient cache policy '. You should actually have a header in the response saying 

cache-control: max-age=2592000, public  .

If not present, then cache control is not enabled. To check the response headers in Chrome, right-click> Inspect > Network. Reload the page, click on any request, you should be able to see headers on the right panel.